# Database rows need to show in column

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have below database table:

```
id       Creation_Date         Goals  Alternative    Value
-----------------------------------------------------------
1   2014-04-17 10:09:30         G1         A         0.86
2   2014-04-17 10:09:30         G1         B         0.87
3   2014-04-17 10:09:30         G2         A         0.5
4   2014-04-17 10:09:30         G2         B         0
```

I am firing below query:

```
  select 
    alternative,
    max( case when goals='G1' then round( value, 2 ) end ) as 'G1',
    max( case when goals='G2' then round( value, 2 ) end ) as 'G2'
    from sgwebdb.dim_module
  group by alternative
  ;
```

and getting below output:

```
 Alternative    G1       G2
-----------------------------
 A            0.86      0.50    
 B            0.87      0.00
```

Now Goals are not pre defined (G1, G2, G3, G4, ...), it can be any number. Can I have a query so that I get the same output without defining a number of goals in the query?

Comment: I think you may need to use dynamic SQL

Comment: When you are not sure on the number of dynamic columns and their names to be generated by the pivot query, you better depend on a stored procedure with prepared statement to construct the sql statement and execute. So that you get results with the column names and values dynamically identified.

Comment: Bobby - I never used dynamic sql .can you help me for this query?

Comment: @Ravinder mate with your help I solved above problem but now I am facing this new problem in same query.i never used stored procedure with c#.

Comment: @vim: Ok. you have a working solution from below answers by `@Uriel_SVK`

Comment: @Ravinder yes that's working absolutely fine in MySQL. Only thing is that I never execute MySQL procedure in c# code.

Comment: @vim: You have a sample code at [*Calling a Stored Procedure from Connector/NET*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-using-stored.html#connector-net-using-stored-calling). This is on MySQL official web site. Go through the `C# Example` there and hope you get a working solution.

Comment: @Ravinder thx mate ,just going to go through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(goals = ''',
      goals,
      ''', round(value, 2), NULL)) AS ',
      goals
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM sgwebdb.dim_module;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT alternative, ', @sql, ' FROM sgwebdb.dim_module GROUP BY alternative');

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
```

Source: http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac9f88/10

Comment: mate this one is working fine in MySQL but only thing is that I never used MySQL procedure in c# code.

Comment: you can make it a stored procedure and call it easily from c#, solution is dependig on what you use for connection - entity? SQL client? there are many examples for both on google. If it wont work pls add problem to your question, or make new question

Comment: we cannot get output without procedure ,I mean to say with help of one single query?

Comment: if you have a stored procedure you can call it in a single query. Otherwise? no idea.. has been years since i worked last time with sql connector

Answer (score 0):

Pivot is what you are looking for, but is apparently not supported in MySQL.  Attached another article that shows how it can be (sortof) done:

http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-table-with-dynamic-columns/